# Word boundry \b in Java RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I am having difficulty with using `\b` as a word delimiter in Java Regex.

For

```
text = "/* sql statement */ INSERT INTO someTable";
```

`Pattern.compile("(?i)\binsert\b");`  no match found

`Pattern insPtrn = Pattern.compile("\bINSERT\b");` no match found

but

`Pattern insPtrn = Pattern.compile("INSERT");`  finds a match

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

When writing regular expressions in Java, you need to be sure to escape all of the backslashes, so the regex `\bINSERT\b` becomes `"\\bINSERT\\b"` as a Java string.

If you do not escape the backslash, then the `\b` in the string literal is interpreted as a backspace character.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead: -

```
Pattern insPtrn = Pattern.compile("\\bINSERT\\b")
```

You need to escape `\b` with an extra backslash..